# How do I trigger a void function with another button?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a `-(void)assignCats` method in my test project, and I need to trigger the code in it from two seperate buttons. I know how to use IBAction, but how do I make two IBActions trigger the same (void)?

Comment: `IBAction` is `void.` What's the problem?

Comment: How do you make two methods call the same method? Call it from both those methods. What did you try? What difficulty did you encounter?

Comment: @uchuugaka, No need of Xcode and cocoa tags in this question. I have removed it from your edit suggestion.

Comment: On the contrary, IBAction is only really relevant to Cocoa, Cocoa touch and Xcode. None of that is Foundation or Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call your method from within the `IBAction` 
methods.

```
-(IBAction)pointAtCats:(id)sender {
   [self assignCats];
}

-(IBAction)laughAtCats:(id)sender {
   [self assignCats];
}
```

`IBAction` is also actually a `void` return `typedef`. It is simply used by Xcode to know what is available for use in interface connections.

Answer (score 2):

Just hook them both up to the same action.  `IBAction` is just defined to be `void`, so you could just change the `assignCats` signature without changing any other program behaviour.  Alternately, write a new action that calls `assignCats` from its implementation.